# To have a look at subset of linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I use R-Studio. I've run this linear regression model:

```
gn<- lm(NA.~ I(PC^0.25) + I(((PI)^2)),data=DSET)
```

Then, I ommited the first 11 elements of the model with the following command:

```
newgn<-update(gn,subset=-c(1:11))
```

I would like to have a look on the console at the first 11 elements which were ommited from the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
model.frame(gn)[1:11,]
```

This will show you the first 11 elements (rows) that were used in the`gn` linear regression.